# Replace word in contenteditable div and properly set caret position

Tags: javascript, range, selection, contenteditable

I've been searching through a lot of Range and Selection related questions (mostly answered by [@tim-down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down)), but I can't quite get what I need, although I come close.

I want to search the currently focused text node for the word `foo`. If I find it - replace it with `bar` and set the caret position at the end of the replaced word. For example:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor foo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
```

Turns into:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor bar amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
// -------------------^--- caret position
```

### My attempt

What I currently have works only halfway - it removes the text, but doesn't add anything. I'm not sure it's the best approach, though:

```js
function replacer(search, replace) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel.focusNode) {
    return;
  }

  var startIndex = sel.focusNode.nodeValue.indexOf(search);
  var endIndex = startIndex + search.length;

  if (startIndex === -1) {
    return;
  }

  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(sel.focusNode, startIndex);
  range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, endIndex);
  range.insertNode(document.createTextNode("bar"));

  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  replacer("foo", "bar");
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;">Lorem ipsum dolor foo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

*Note: I only care for compatibility with Chrome.*

Comment: What if there are multiple `foo` in in your contenteditable? What should happen and where should the cursor be places at?

Comment: @vsync the caret should be placed at the last occurrence of `foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explain in code comment and console log.

See about [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

```js
function replacer(search, replace) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel.focusNode) {
    return;
  }

  var startIndex = sel.focusNode.nodeValue.indexOf(search);
  var endIndex = startIndex + search.length;
  if (startIndex === -1) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("first focus node: ", sel.focusNode.nodeValue);
  var range = document.createRange();
  //Set the range to contain search text
  range.setStart(sel.focusNode, startIndex);
  range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, endIndex);
  //Delete search text
  range.deleteContents();
  console.log("focus node after delete: ", sel.focusNode.nodeValue);
  //Insert replace text
  range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replace));
  console.log("focus node after insert: ", sel.focusNode.nodeValue);
  //Move the caret to end of replace text
  sel.collapse(sel.focusNode, 0);
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  replacer("foo", "bar");
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;" id='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor foo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain why it works, though? Shouldn't the caret be set at the first character of the text node, I.E. before the word "Lorem"?

Comment: I update my answer to add comment and console log. Please check it and feel  free to ask more question.

Comment: @Duannx can you please see this when i type foo caret go to the first place. and i have change textnode to html node. can you please see below [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyvzh4wm/1/)

Comment: @sidoshi: I saw your fiddle. But what is the problem?

Comment: @Duannx can you please type foo on last. it will replace with bar but caret will go another place.

Comment: @sidoshi yes. I saw it

Comment: @Duannx is there any solution?

Comment: @sidoshi: Why not do the same as my answer above?

Comment: @Duannx beacuse i have html inside a contenteditable div. not the plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Using `createNodeIterator` to iterate all textNodes with `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT`, it is easy to hunt down all occurrences of the string `foo` and replace with anything desired, `bar` textNode in this case.

The second stage, which should be decoupled from the find-and-replace function, is the caret placement request, and is implemented by the function `setRangeAtEnd`, which receives a single argument, `node`, which is available from the output of the first function, `replaceTextWithNode`, which returns an Array of all the nodes replaced in the *contentEditable*.

```js
const elm = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]');

function replaceTextWithNode( elm, text, replacerNode ){
  var iter = document.createNodeIterator(elm, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT),
      textnode, replacedNode, idx, newNode,
      maxIterations = 100,
      addedNodes = [];

  while( textnode = iter.nextNode() ){
      if( !maxIterations-- ) break;
      // get the index of which the text is within the textNode (if at all)
      idx = textnode.nodeValue.indexOf(text)
      if( idx == -1 ) continue
      
      replacedNode = textnode.splitText(idx)
      newNode = replacerNode.cloneNode()

      // clean up the tag's string and put tag element instead
      replacedNode.nodeValue = replacedNode.nodeValue.replace(text, '')
      textnode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, replacedNode)
      addedNodes.push(newNode)
  }

  return addedNodes
}


function setRangeAtEnd( node ){
  node = node.firstChild || node;
  const sel = document.getSelection()

  if( sel.rangeCount )
      ['Start', 'End'].forEach(pos =>
          sel.getRangeAt(0)["set" + pos](node, node.length)
      )
}

// Replace all 'foo' with 'bar' textNodes
var addedNodes = replaceTextWithNode(elm, 'foo', document.createTextNode('bar'))

// Place caret at last occurrence of 'bar'
elm.focus()
setRangeAtEnd(addedNodes[addedNodes.length-1])
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Lorem ipsum foo dolor foo amet foo, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Comment: What if only specific occurence was to be replaced ?

Answer (score 0):

sidoshi, This fixes the caret positioning after the replacement

```js
function replacer(search, replace) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel.focusNode) {
    return;
  }

  var startIndex = sel.focusNode.nodeValue.indexOf(search);
  var endIndex = startIndex + search.length;
  if (startIndex === -1) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("first focus node: ", sel.focusNode.nodeValue);
  var range = document.createRange();
  //Set the range to contain search text
  range.setStart(sel.focusNode, startIndex);
  range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, endIndex);
  //Delete search text
  range.deleteContents();
  console.log("focus node after delete: ", sel.focusNode.nodeValue);
  //Insert replace text
  range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replace));
  console.log("focus node after insert: ", sel.focusNode.nodeValue);
  //Move the caret to end of replace text
  var replacement = document.createTextNode(replace); 
  range.insertNode(replacement);
  range.setStartAfter(replacement);                       
  // Chrome fix
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range); 
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  replacer("foo", "bar");
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;" id='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor foo amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

This isn't exactly what was asked for but loops multiple replacements and handles DIV as above and textareas equally well.

```js
var replaceValues = {
    'foo' : 'bar',
    'aaa': 'bbbb'
}

$('.macroenabled').keyup(function(e) {
  // change to keypress if you want it to happen after space
  for (var search in replaceValues) {
    if ($(document.activeElement).is(":input")) {
      var newText = $(e.target).val();
      var temp = new RegExp(search, 'gim');
      newText = newText.replace(temp, replaceValues[search]);
      $(e.target).val(newText);
    } else { // element contenteditable DIV
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      if (!sel.focusNode || ! sel.focusNode.nodeValue) { // Nothing focused
        continue;
      }
      var startIndex = sel.focusNode.nodeValue.indexOf(search);
      var endIndex = startIndex + search.length;
      if (startIndex === -1) { // search not found
        continue;
      }
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.setStart(sel.focusNode, startIndex);
      range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, endIndex);
      range.deleteContents(); //Delete search text
      var replacement = document.createTextNode(replaceValues[search]); 
      range.insertNode(replacement);
      range.setStartAfter(replacement);                       
      sel.removeAllRanges(); // Chrome fix
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I am a textarea, try 'aaa' or 'foo'</div>
<textarea class="macroenabled"></textarea>
<div>I am a content editable DIV, try 'aaa' or 'foo'</div>
<div id="div1" contenteditable="true" class="macroenabled"></div>
```